# days to hours using date() function

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have time in minutes and I want to find out how many hours it is. But with attached code, for 1600 minutes, I get 2 hours and 40 minutes. I need it in format 26:40:00. Thanks for help.

```
$my_time = 1600;
echo date("H:i:s", $my_time);
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  The answer will vary depending on this.

Comment: `26:40:00`? Do you mean `2:40:00` or am I missing something?

Comment: No, the OP is correct.  1600 minutes is 26 hours, 40 minutes, and 0 seconds.

Comment: @RayToal Your explanation had merit on its own, so I wouldn't say it is exactly the same as my answer.

Comment: @Asad thanks but you captured everything perfectly with the phrase "specifically built to handle intervals".  But you might have a point though, I soooooo wish programmers would understand the distinction between instants and durations.  Why is time so hard?  In space, we understand "point vs. distance" but when it comes to time, people just don't get it.  Oh well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, which is specifically built to handle intervals of time:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('M1600');
echo $interval->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: @RayToal You deleted your explanation which I thought was a good addition to Asad's answer. Maybe you put it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

`date` isn't really suited for this. Instead, try this:

```
echo sprintf("%s:%2s:%2s",floor($my_time/3600),floor($my_time/60)%60,$my_time%60);
```

(This is assuming you have `$my_time` in seconds, not minutes. Multiply by `60` up front to get the time in seconds)

Comment: OP said he had minutes. I think it would be easier to adjust the function, rather than tweak the input to fit the function.